# Как реализовать алгоритм поиска противника в игре?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть режим игры с 2 мя и с 3 мя игроками.
Выберает режим игры (2x,3x) и нажимает поиск игры.
Использую websocket для связи.
Какой алгоритм необходим для оптимальной работы поиска противников. (На примере игры морской бой 2)

Как правильно реализовать логику этого функционала?

Comment: Рейтинг Эло, можно даже без переделок.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я не совсем это имел ввиду. Например игрок нажал "В Бой", дальше допустим где то на сервере (в таблице ...) добавился этот игрок со статусом свободный и т.д., потом еще один игрок готов к бою... как правильно соединять этих двух (трех) игроков. Есть специальное определение для реализации этой части игры?

Comment: вам нужно сервер для нескольких человек реализовать или алгоритм поиска противников для морского боя ? https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Интик В игре есть 2 режима: играют двое, или трое. Когда каждый игрок отправляет на сервер сообщение что он готов к игре определенно режима, сервер должен соединять свободных игроков соответствующего режима. Хочу понять как правильно реализовать это?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27491016/7485582

Answer (score 3):

Каждому игроку необходимо присваивать уникальный id. При входе в игру необходимо устанавливать соединение с сервером и регистрировать каждого нового игрока как свободного, с сохранением в список таких игроков. От каждого свободного игрока необходимо периодически получать подтверждение доступности. Подобрав пару или тройку участников, нужно каждому игроку вывести информацию об установки соединения.
Если один из них не ответит, то необходимо заменить данного участника.
После окончания игры участников опять помещать в список доступных.

При подборе соперников можно учитывать послужной список и (или) географию, интересы и т.п. Данную информацию можно сохранять для каждого участника игры. Можно сделать возможность задания фильтра при поиске соперников. Тогда за выбор более сильного игрока можно давать дополнительные балы.